# selecting from the table where the display_start date is minimum

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what I want though can't find the proper syntax.
eg.

```
select * from campaign where campaign_display_start is minimum;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM campaign WHERE campaign_display_start = 
(
 SELECT MIN(campaign_display_start) FROM campaign
)
```

As per your requirement you can use below one

```
SELECT *
FROM campaign 
WHERE campaign_display_start =
(
  SELECT MIN(campaign_display_start) FROM campaign 
  WHERE campaign_display_start>now()
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I solve this by using this query.                                       
>>select * from campaign where campaign_display_start>now() 
    ORDER BY campaign_display_start LIMIT 1

Comment: But limit 1 will give only 1 row, If more than 1 row having same value then your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from campaign ORDER BY campaign_display_start LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If there is more than 1 row with minimum date then??